# Sybase bcp in works with fast bcp if trigger is disabled?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, bcp

I want to know if the fast bcp works for a table that has triggers disables, or do I have to remove the triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Sybase doc, on ASE15.0, disabling the trigger won't help bcp to use the fast mode:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility62.htm

=> If space is available, you can use drop index and drop trigger to drop all the indexes and triggers beforehand.

in ASE15.7 ESD#3, the doc seems to indicate that the triggers are not a problem for fast-bcp:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1573/html/utilityguide/utilityguide63.htm

To be tested...

Comment: I've also read the documentation but I still have that doubt. And in the documentation doesn't states anything about triggers disables. It says we need to drop them but isn't it the same thing?

Comment: I am afraid that the trigger needs to be removed. An old thread (2008) seems to confirm it. What I don't know is for the last version of ASE. http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C47e3d7d3.56fc.1681692777@sybase.com%3E